# Passing a WKB generated by Geopandas into an Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY constructor

Tags: geopandas, oracle-spatial, well-known-binary, cx-oracle

I'm trying to iteratively pass WKBs created by Geopandas into an Oracle SQL query but I'm getting this error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.sql.SQLException: Malformed WKT
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_JAVA_STP", line 79
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 5188
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY", line 76
ORA-06512: at line
```

Here is a snippet of the code I'm trying:

```
aoi = 'some_shapefile.shp'
sql = """ SELECT* 
          FROM table b 
          WHERE SDO_RELATE (b.SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(:wkb, :srid),'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE' """ 

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, hostname, encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = connection.cursor()

gdf = gpd.read_file(aoi)
srid = gdf.crs.to_epsg()
wkb = gdf['geometry'].to_wkb().iloc[0] 
            
bvars = {'wkb': wkb, 'srid': srid} 
cursor.execute(sql,bvars)

rows = cursor.fetchall()
colnames = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=colnames)
```

Please note that replacing WKB by WKT in the above code works fine. However some geometries  have a lot of vertices which results in WKT strings longer than the VARCHAR limit. That is why I'm trying to use WKB blobs instead.

Comment: WKB is a BLOB type, while WKT is CLOB (not VARCHAR2)

Comment: Have you tried to use FROM_WKBGEOMETRY https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_util-from_wktgeometry.htm#SPATL1234 in your SQL? But I guess that it does the same as your simple syntax that is documented in https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-constructors.htm#SPATL501. Perhaps Oracle does not like the WKB that Geopandas create.

Comment: I see one oddity: the error message of the exception is `java.sql.SQLException: Malformed WKT` which is odd since you are trying to process a WKB. So, this can mean one of two things: the variable you pass to the SQL statement is actually recognized by the database as a text string, so is interpreted as a WKT (and that obviously then fails), or it is a bug in the exception handling mechanism that returns the wrong message ...

Comment: I checked the source code for this process. The exception you get is from an old Oracle version (12.1 or even older). After that release, we throw more find-grained exceptions that specify what is wrong with the WKT string. But the key thing is this: that exception is thrown in the code path that deals specifically with WKT input.  If the input was invalid WKB, you would have gotten a different exception. To me that confirms my first suspicion, that somehow you are passing a string or string array to the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers and comments.
I solved the error by adding this line before executing the query:

```
cursor.setinputsizes(wkb=cx_Oracle.BLOB).
```

It looks like the WKB needs to be explicitly defined as cx_Oracle BLOB before passing it into the SDO_Geometry constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the implementation of the WKT/WKB to SDO_GEOMETRY, I see that this specific exception (`java.sql.SQLException: Malformed WKT`) only exists in older releases of Oracle (12.1 and earlier). Since 12.2 it is replaced with an exception message that returns mode details about what the nature of the error is. But the key fact is: this message comes only in the code path that processes **WKT**. It does **not** occur in the path that processes **WKB**.

So, my suspicion is that the code you execute ...

```
aoi = 'some_shapefile.shp'
sql = """ SELECT* 
          FROM table b 
          WHERE SDO_RELATE (b.SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(:wkb, :srid),'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE' """ 

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, hostname, encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = connection.cursor()

gdf = gpd.read_file(aoi)
srid = gdf.crs.to_epsg()
wkb = gdf['geometry'].to_wkb().iloc[0] 
            
bvars = {'wkb': wkb, 'srid': srid} 
cursor.execute(sql,bvars)
```

... somehow passes the `wkb` variable as a string, which then appears as a WKT input to the SDO_GEOMETRY constructor.

Can you try the following alternate syntax that explicitly calls the WKB parser ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table b 
WHERE SDO_RELATE (b.SHAPE, set_srid(SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKBGEOMETRY(:wkb),:srid),'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'
```

Note that the `SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKBGEOMETRY()` function does not let you pass an explicit SRID. So, before doing the above, you need to define a simple function `SET_SRID()` that sets the SRID of a geometry:

```
create or replace function set_srid (g sdo_geometry, srid number) return sdo_geometry
is
  gs sdo_geometry;
begin
  gs := g;
  gs.sdo_srid := srid;
  return gs;
end;
/
```

and use that in the SELECT statement as shown.

Then your query should work (it works for me with this change)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Albert Godfrind. It helped to steer me in the right direction. I solved the error by adding this line before executing the query: cursor.setinputsizes(wkb=cx_Oracle.BLOB). It looks like the WKB needs to be clearly defined as cx_Oracle BLOB.

Comment: Great. This is good to know.